# How to update JInternalFrame by click button on JDialog (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am creating a MDI Application by Java.
I design a JInternalFrame

```
public class account extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame
```

[{`account` GUI here}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7zdc.png)
that show data get from SQL. On this `account`, I create a JButton named `btnReName`

```
private javax.swing.JButton btnReName;
```

to open a new JDialog `ReName`.

```
public class ReName extends javax.swing.JDialog
```

This JDialog `ReName` is created to change the name in SQL. After rename successfull, I click on a JButton named `btnConfirm`

```
private javax.swing.JButton btnConfirm;
```

to close this JDialog. After click button `Confirm`, a JOption appear
[like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z41wG.jpg) I want after click `OK`, the JDialog `ReName` is closed, and at the same time, the data on the JInternalFrame `account` update exactly to what i changed in this JDialog `ReName` by re-query data from SQL(in other words, i want to update the `account` by clicking on a Button `btnConfirm` created on `ReName` that opened by this JInternalFrame `account`)
but i dont know how to design it.
Can someone guide me how to create the Button with the function like i was description?
[Link to my full-code](https://github.com/ngochieu2004/demoGameJava)

Comment: I use Netbeans on MacOS so the display is diffrent from Windows.

Comment: what i want here is when i close `ReName` , `account` will automatically call back its constructor to refresh the data inside without having to resort to the parameters passed back from `ReName`

Comment: I push all my code on github https://github.com/ngochieu2004/demoGameJava
you can download it and see all my application design. Hope this helps you to understand better

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  It's your responsibility to take the information provided by @Abra and others and apply it to your application.

Comment: sorry because my English is not good, so i don't know clearly what part of my code he want, so i public all my code to help him know clearly about my situation. I just want to ask about how to solve the problem in my case, not write the code for me

Comment: My code write to get data from database and show it, and with my knowlege, i cannot create any minimal, reproducible example for my case. My code is still working fine, and what I want here is to make the user experience seamless by automatically updating the data that the user changes without any further action.

Answer (score 2):

The below code does what you want. I did not find a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question so I guessed that you are using a [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to display the *Player Information*. I also only added the *Rename* button since your question only concerns that button. Here is the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GamePlay {
    private JFrame  frame;

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        Account iFrame = new Account("iFrame");
        iFrame.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(iFrame);
        frame.setContentPane(desktop);
        frame.setSize(600, 580);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new GamePlay().createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class Account extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton  btnReName;
    private JTable  table;

    public Account(String title) {
        super(title);
        String[] columnNames = {"Ten Nguoi Choi","So Lan Thang","So Lan Choi"};
        Object[][] data = {{"Player Name", 1, 7},
                           {"Nguoi choi 1", 10, 10},
                           {"Nguoi choi 2", 10, 100},
                           {"Nguoi choi 3", 0, 10}};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        btnReName = new JButton("Rename");
        btnReName.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(btnReName);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        ReName dlg = new ReName(this);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void changeName(String newName) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (row >= 0) {
            table.setValueAt(newName, row, 0);
        }
    }
}

class ReName extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private Account  account;
    private JButton  btnConfirm;
    private JButton  cancel;
    private JPasswordField  passwordField;
    private JTextField  nameTextField;

    public ReName(Account acct) {
        account = acct;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        add(createForm(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(createButtons(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(acct);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                                      "Successful",
                                      "Noitication",
                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        dispose();
        account.changeName(nameTextField.getText());
    }

    private JPanel createButtons() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        btnConfirm.addActionListener(this);
        cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        panel.add(cancel);
        panel.add(btnConfirm);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createForm() {
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Enter new name:");
        form.add(nameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        nameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        form.add(nameTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        form.add(passwordLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        form.add(passwordField, gbc);
        return form;
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, the GUI initially looks as follows (using JDK 11 on Windows 10)

[image: initial gui]

This is a screen capture after selecting the name to change and pressing button *Rename*.

[image: after press rename]

This is a screen capture after entering the new name and pressing button *Confirm*.

[image: after confirm]

And finally, a screen capture after pressing button *OK*. Notice that the first column of the selected row in the `JTable` has changed to what was entered in the `JDialog`.

[image: after OK]

Comment: The function of the button is exactly what I need, but the table  does not like that. all the data is get from SQL database. I push all my code in github-https://github.com/ngochieu2004/demoGameJava 
you can download and test on it. I hope you understand what I want to convey

Comment: *"I hope you understand what I want to convey"* I hope you understand that a) People worth listening to won't be following a link. All relevant code should be in the question itself. b) *"but the table does not like that"* That explains nothing.